How to scatter multiple clipped 'decal' textures over a surface
I want to scatter multiple manhole textures across a road surface I’ve created using geometry nodes. I use "store named attribute" nodes to transfer the UV coordinates.
The manhole images have transparent backgrounds.
So far, this is the approach I've come up with:

I start with an asphalt material as a base using a Principled BSDF.
For the manhole textures, I also use Principled BSDFs, setting the image texture nodes to "Clip" instead of "Repeat."
I combine these Principled BSDFs with "Mix Shader" nodes.
I use mapping nodes to control the placement of the manholes.

My question is: how can I scatter several of these clipped manholes across the surface, ideally not allowing them to overlap?
The Blender file is here:




